# How to drop objects from git repo?

Tags: backup, git, repository, commit

I have a git repo for backup, I used to let it backup many useless but large files, which is a stupid mistake. I untracked those files long time ago.

When I recently git clone the repo, it's really slow, I think that's because the useless files in the commit history(we will copy objects of those obsolete file too).

Does anyone knows how to delete those trash from the repo, thanks.

Comment: There are some instructions on [so]. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I think https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data totally solve my problem, thanks @Oliver for the clue.